# Flush Catalog Images Cache from migration file

Tags: php, magento, caching, data-migration

I had to change the images from

> images\catalog\product\placeholder

but the problem is that the old images are still displaying because of cache in

> media\catalog\product\cache

I found in the backend in System -> Cache Management the option to flush the images cache and it works great, but I need to do this from a migration file in order to flush this cache for everyone who works on my project.

So I searched for the code of backend button and it looks like this
 `<button onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCleanImagesUrl()?>')" type="button" ....`
And in my migration file I tryed to do this

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/cache_additional');
$block->getCleanImagesUrl();
```

But with no result.
Can someone give me an idea on how to flush the cache from a migration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should clean the images cache:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_image')->clearCache();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was easier than i thought!